# Find the index of the last non-zero element in each row of a given matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

For an arbitrary sized matrix `x`, how do I find the index of the last non-zero element in each row of a given matrix?

For example, for the matrix

```
x = [ 0 9 7 0 0 0; 5 0 0 6 0 3; 0 0 0 0 0 0; 8 0 4 2 1 0 ]
```

the vector `[ 3 6 0 5 ]` should be obtained.

Comment: This wouldn't happen to be homework, would it?

Comment: this looks rather like homework to me...

Comment: Yes it does, but it's a fun question.

Comment: I knew I've seen a similar question (had it in my favorite list): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831721/turning-a-matlab-binary-matrix-into-a-vector-of-the-last-nonzero-index-in-a-fast

Answer (score 10):

Here's a shorter version, combining [find](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html) and [accumarray](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html)

```
x = [ 0 9 7 0 0 0; 5 0 0 6 0 3; 0 0 0 0 0 0; 8 0 4 2 1 0 ];
%# get the row and column indices for x
[rowIdx,colIdx] = find(x);
%# with accumarray take the maximum column index for every row
v = accumarray(rowIdx,colIdx,[],@max)'
v =
     3   6   0   5
```

Comment: nice accumarray usage, i'll try to remember it. +1

Answer (score 4):

Here's one version:

```
x = [ 0 9 7 0 0 0; 5 0 0 6 0 3; 0 0 0 0 0 0; 8 0 4 2 1 0 ];
c = arrayfun(@(k) find(x(k,:)~=0,1,'last'), 1:size(x,1), 'UniformOutput',false);
c( cellfun(@isempty,c) ) = {0};
v = cell2mat(c);

v =
     3     6     0     5
```

---

**EDIT**:
Consider this alternative solution:

```
[m,v] = max( cumsum(x'~=0) );
v(m==0) = 0;

v =
     3     6     0     5
```

Comment: you cab probably write a better vectorized solution using a combination of CUMSUM and DIFF.. Let's see if I can figure one out :)

Comment: @Jack Lu: If you find a solution useful, please consider upvoting/accepting it.

Comment: What does the '~= mean?  Transpose of x and then check every point where cell not equal to zero?

Comment: @hhh: [`~=`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ne.html) is the element-wise inequality operator. The transpose is just a detail here, we could have explicitly specified the dimension along which to work: `[m,v] = max(cumsum(x~=0,2),[],2)`. The next line handles the case where a row was all zeros

Answer (score 2):

One-line solution with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
result = max(bsxfun(@times, x~=0, 1:size(x,2)).');
```

Or use the two outputs of [`max`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html):

```
[val, result] = max(fliplr(x~=0).',[],1); %'
result = (size(A,2)+1-result).*val;
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer's a bit twisted but it should work too

```
x = [ 0 9 7 0 0 0; 5 0 0 6 0 3; 0 0 0 0 0 0; 8 0 4 2 1 0 ];
[~,pos] = max([fliplr(x~=0),ones(size(x,1))],[],2);
v = size(x,2)-pos' +1;
```

Comment: true, bad cut & paste, fixed now.