# Order of elements in cell array constructed by accumarray

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

What I'm trying to do: given a 2D matrix, get the column indices of the elements in each row that satisfy some particular condition.

For example, say my matrix is

```
M = [16 2 3 13; 5 11 10 8; 9 7 6 12; 4 14 15 1]
```

and my condition is `M>6`. Then my desired output would be something like

```
Indices = {[1 4]'; [2 3 4]'; [1 2 4]'; [2 3]';}
```

After reading the answers to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910264/find-the-index-of-the-last-non-zero-element-in-each-row-of-a-given-matrix) I came up with this partial solution using `find` and `accumarray`:

```
[ix, iy] = find(M>6);
Indices = accumarray(ix,iy,[],@(iy){iy});
```

This gives very nearly the results I want -- in fact, the indices are all right, but they're not ordered the way I expected. For example, `Indices{2} = [2 4 3]'` instead of `[2 3 4]'`, and I can't understand why. There are 3 occurrences of `2` in `ix`, at indices `3`, `6`, and `9`. The corresponding values of `iy` at those indices are `2`, `3`, and `4`, in that order. What exactly is creating the observed order? Is it just arbitrary? Is there a way to force it to be what I want, other than sorting each element of `Indices` afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to solve it with **[`arrayfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html)** -

```
idx = arrayfun(@(x) find(M(x,:)>6),1:size(M,1),'Uni',0)
```

Display output wtih `celldisp(idx)` -

```
idx{1} =
     1     4
idx{2} =
     2     3     4
idx{3} =
     1     2     4
idx{4} =
     2     3
```

---

To continue working with `accumarray`, you can wrap `iy` with `sort` to get your desired output which doesn't look too pretty maybe -

```
Indices = accumarray(ix,iy,[],@(iy){sort(iy)})
```

Output -

```
>> celldisp(Indices)
Indices{1} =
     1
     4
Indices{2} =
     2
     3
     4
Indices{3} =
     1
     2
     4
Indices{4} =
     2
     3
```

Comment: Beautiful! I didn't know about arrayfun. I'm still a little curious why my attempted approach doesn't quite work, but this seems like the perfect solution to my actual problem.

Comment: @CurtisH. Your apporach is good; it's just that `accumarray` does not preserve order

Comment: @CurtisH. I think you can wrap `iy` with `sort`. Added code for that.

Comment: @Divakar That seems to work too, but your `arrayfun` solution is substantially faster, at least on my actual data.

Comment: @CurtisH. That's good to know! I think `accumarray` based approaches are efficient when you are getting numeric outputs from them, otherwise when working with `anonymous functions` its performance drops significantly, I don't have numbers to prove that though. This same story continues with `bsxfun + anonymous functions` for which luckily I do have numbers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592765/generating-arrays-using-bsxfun-with-anonymous-function-and-for-elementwise-subtr/26593369#comment41803858_26593369).

Answer (score 2):

[`accumarray`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) is not guaranteed to preserve order of each chunk of its second input (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17775147/2586922), and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17537523/2586922)). However, it does seem to preserve it when the first input is already sorted:

```
[iy, ix] = find(M.'>6); %'// transpose and reverse outputs, to make ix sorted
Indices = accumarray(ix,iy,[],@(iy){iy}); %// this line is the same as yours
```

produces

```
Indices{1} =
     1
     4

Indices{2} =
     2
     3
     4

Indices{3} =
     1
     2
     4

Indices{4} =
     2
     3
```

Comment: Thank you, that would explain it. I should have read the `accumarray` documentation more carefully.