# Use a vector as an index to a matrix

Tags: matlab, indexing, matrix

I'm writing a MATLAB function to read out data into an n-dimensional array (variable dimension size). I need to be able to access a specific point in the Matrix (to write to it or read it, for example), but I don't know ahead of time how many indexes to specify.

Currently I have a `current_point` vector which I iterate through to specify each index, and a `max_points` vector which specifies the size of the array. So, if for example I wanted a 3-dimensional array of size 1000-by-15-by-3, `max_points = [1000 15 3]`, and `current_point` iterates from `[1, 1, 1]` to `[1000, 15, 3]` (`[1, 1, 1]` -> `[1000, 1, 1]` -> `[1, 2, 1]` -> `[1000, 2, 1]` ->...). What I'd like to be able to do is feed `current_point` as an index to the matrix like so:

```
output_matrix(current_point) = val
```

But apparently something like `output_matrix([1 2 3]) = val` will just set `outputmatrix(1:3) = 30`. I can't just use dummy variables because sometimes the matrix will need 3 indexes, other times 4, other times 2, etc, so a vector of variable length is really what I need here. Is there a simple way to use a vector as the points in an index?

Comment: This is *essentially* a duplicate of [Compact MATLAB matrix indexing notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792683/compact-matlab-matrix-indexing-notation), although maybe this question is a little simpler than that case.

Comment: I knew this must've been asked before, but couldn't find it with my dupe plugin. I guess I'll let the answer stay, as the question title is more direct than the other one and might be easier to search.

Comment: I figured that it must have been asked at some point, but from the titles I wasn't seeing anything. Good answers from both of you guys. I figured there would be something simple like that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using the function [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to create a [linear index](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) is the typical solution to this problem, as shown in this [closely-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/792683/52738). You could also [compute a linear index yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1146719/52738) instead of calling `sub2ind`.

However, your case may be simpler than those in the other questions I linked to. If you're only ever indexing a *single* point with your `current_point` vector (i.e. it's just an n-element vector of subscripts into your n-dimensional matrix), then you can use a simple solution where you convert `current_point` to a cell array of subscripts using the function [`num2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) and use it to create a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) of indices. For example:

```
current_point = [1 2 3 ...];        % A 1-by-n array of subscripts
subCell = num2cell(current_point);  % A 1-by-n cell array of subscripts
output_matrix(subCell{:}) = val;    % Update the matrix point
```

The operation `subCell{:}` creates the equivalent of typing `subCell{1}, subCell{2}, ...`, which is the equivalent of typing `current_point(1), current_point(2), ...`.

Answer (score 10):

I know it is too late but for anybody who will find this topic. the easiest way that work for me is to use: `diag(A (x(:),y(:)) )`;

unfortunately this works only if you need to get values from the matrix, not for changing values

Comment: Can you explain this further, I dont understand it but it looks like it could be a nice and simple solution

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sub2ind.html) function to get the linear index from the subscript.

**Example:**

```
A=magic(4)

A =

    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1

selectElement={2,3}; %# get the element at position 2,3 in A.
indx=sub2ind(size(A),selectElement{:});
A(indx)

ans =

    10
```

In the above example, I've stored the subscripts (can be any number of dimensions) as a `cell`. If you have it stored as a vector, simply use [`num2cell()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/num2cell.html) to convert it to a cell.

You can now easily assign a value to this as `A(indx)=value;`. I've used different variables than yours to keep the answer general, but the idea is the same and you just need to replace the variable names.

You also mentioned in your post that you're looping from `(1,1,1)` till some value, `(1000,15,3)` and assigning a value to each of these points. If you're looping along the columns, you can replace this entire operation with a vectorized solution.

Let `finalElement={1000,15,3}` be the final step of the loop. As before, find the linear index as

```
index=sub2ind(size(A),finalElement{:});
```

Now if you have the values you assign in the loop stored as a single vector, `values`, you can simply assign it in a single step as

```
A(1:index)=values;
```