# Adding multiple rows of a table to another table

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

I have a table as below : (This is a few lines from my table)

```
T = table({'A';'A';'A';'B';'B';'B';'C';'C';'C';'C'}, {'x';'y';'z';'x';'w';'t';'z';'x';'t';'o'},[5;1;2;2;4;2;2;5;4;1], ...
      'VariableNames', {'memberId', 'productId','Rating'});
```

T:

```
A  x  5
A  y  1
Z  z  2
B  x  2
B  w  4
B  t  2
C  z  2
C  x  5
C  t  4
C  o  1
C  u  3
D  r  1
D  t  2
D  w  5
.
.
.
.
```

I need to take the user A then Create a table like Previous table (Table T) and All rows are related to the user A to enter that table.At this point in the table are the following lines:

```
A  x  5
A  y  1
A  z  2
```

Next, consider products related to this user  i.e x,y,z . then All lines that contain x and then y and z are adding to the table. At this point in the table are the following lines:

```
A  x  5
A  y  1
A  z  2
B  x  2
C  z  2
C  x  5
```

Then, other users have been added to the table to consider i.e B,C . Then The same thing was done for the first user (A) is done for this user (Respectively for B then C).
This is done so that the required number of rows add in the table. Here, for example, 8 rows is required.  i.e The end result is as follows:

```
A  x  5
A  y  1
A  z  2
B  x  2
C  z  2
C  x  5
B  w  4
B  t  2
```

i.e when work is finished the requested number of rows in the second table row to be imported.

I would be grateful if any body help me in this regard.

Comment: so all entries from the orginal table will be there only in a different order?

Comment: no. I want to do processing on the final table. My original table is very large and represents a graph. I choose this part of the graph, and I want to do some processing on it

Comment: I believe Finn's question is are all entries from the original table present in the new table - just the ordering has changed.

Comment: so you will input the users that will be used or this will run until there is no connection between the remaining users and their productIds?

Comment: no It is not ordering. you suppose my original table has 100 rows and I want 20 rows from it.(for example).

Comment: no I will run until the final table, to have the desired number of rows. ( In question I said original table has 10 row and second table will have 8 row. I said this example because The reader, understand my question Reduction)

Comment: Do you understand my question?

Comment: is the order in the final table of importance?

Comment: I can say that is not important order at the final table. but order in x , y , z is important  or order in B and C ,......

Comment: but Even if you can solve this problem that not order in x,y,z , .....I am grateful.

Comment: i still dont get it if you do tose steps for A,B and C you will end up with all lines. There are only 8 because you only did this for A and B. So do you give A and B or how does the procedure start and end?

Comment: If the algorithm will continue to end, all rows in the main table are included. But we have only a certain number of rows (8 rows) need. The final condition is that the eight row of the original table is entered to second table.

Comment: I should have gone steps somewhere that a certain number of rows from original table  are imported into the second table. It is important.

Comment: What happens if the next set of rows to be added is greater than the rows left to be added. Say there are 7 rows for user A, and now you want to add 5 rows for products x,y,z, but you have only one open slot for a new row - which row you pick? or maybe you leave it empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way for doing what you ask for (though some cases are not well defined in your question):

```
% I added user 'D' for the scenario of an unconnected node
T = table({'A';'A';'A';'B';'B';'B';'C';'C';'C';'C';'D';'D';'D';'D'},...
    {'x';'y';'z';'x';'w';'t';'z';'x';'t';'o';'q';'p';'f';'v'},...
    [5;1;2;2;4;2;2;5;4;1;4;5;2;1], ...
    'VariableNames', {'memberId', 'productId','Rating'});
% initial preparations:
rows_limit = 8;
first_user = 'B'; % this is just for readability
newT = table(cell(rows_limit,1),cell(rows_limit,1),zeros(rows_limit,1),...
    'VariableNames',{'memberId', 'productId','Rating'});
% We need an index vector so we won't add the same row twice:
added = false(height(T),1);
row_count = 1;
users_list = {first_user};

% now we start adding rows to newT until it's full: 
while row_count<rows_limit
    while numel(users_list)>=1
        % get all the user's rows
        next_to_add = strcmp(T.memberId,users_list{1}) & ~added;
        % if this user has any rows to be added:
        if sum(next_to_add)>0
            % if there's enough empty rows in newT add them to it:
            if  sum(next_to_add) <= rows_limit-row_count+1
                newT(row_count:row_count+sum(next_to_add)-1,:) = T(next_to_add,:)
                % and update the index vector:
                added = added | strcmp(T.memberId,users_list{1});
            else
                % otherwise - fill the empty rows and quit the loop:
                if row_count <= rows_limit
                    end_to_add = find(next_to_add,rows_limit-row_count+1);
                    newT(row_count:rows_limit,:) = T(end_to_add,:)
                end
                row_count = rows_limit+1; % to exit the outer loop
                break
            end
            row_count = row_count+sum(next_to_add);

            % Add related products:
            % ====================
            % save the first new user to be addaed by related products:
            last_user_row = row_count;
            % get all the products we already added to newT:
            products = unique(newT.productId(1:row_count-1),'stable');
            % although we want only the last user products, because we add all the
            % products the before, our index vector ('added') will eliminate them
            for p = 1:numel(products)
                % get all the product's rows
                next_to_add = strcmp(T.productId,products{p}) & ~added;
                % if there's enough empty rows in newT add them to it:
                if sum(next_to_add)>0
                    if sum(next_to_add) <= rows_limit-row_count+1
                        newT(row_count:row_count+sum(next_to_add)-1,:) = T(next_to_add,:);
                        % and update the index vector:
                        added = added | strcmp(T.productId,products{p});
                    else
                        % otherwise - fill the empty rows and quit the loop:
                        if row_count <= rows_limit
                            end_to_add = find(next_to_add,rows_limit-row_count+1);
                            newT(row_count:rows_limit,:) = T(end_to_add,:);
                        end
                        row_count = rows_limit+1; % to exit the outer loop
                        break
                    end
                end
                row_count = row_count+sum(next_to_add);
            end
        end
        % get the list of new users we just added, and concat to the users
        % left in the original list:
        users_list = [unique(newT.memberId(last_user_row:row_count-1),'stable');
            unique(T.memberId(~added),'stable')];
    end
end
```

Which gives `newT`:

```
memberId    productId    Rating
________    _________    ______
'B'         'x'          2     
'B'         'w'          4     
'B'         't'          2     
'A'         'x'          5     
'C'         'x'          5     
'C'         't'          4     
'A'         'y'          1     
'A'         'z'          2
```

In this implementation, the rows are added user by user, and product by product, and if the next user/product to be added has more rows then what's available in `newT`, then we add as much rows as we cen, until we get to the `rows_limit` and then the loop quits.

So for a `rows_limit = 4;`, you will get `newT` as:

```
memberId    productId    Rating
________    _________    ______
'B'         'x'          2     
'B'         'w'          4     
'B'         't'          2     
'A'         'x'          5
```

As long as there are connections between users, so each user's related products brings new users to the list, the loop continues with the new users in `newT`. However, it could be that we start from a node that not all other nodes are parts of its network. For instance, have a look a the following graph figure that illustrates the connections in the extended example I used in the code above:

[image: users_net]

Node `D` is not connected to all others, so unless we actively look for new unrelated users in `T`, we will never get to it. The implementation above does look for this kind of users.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but for row_limit=4 ,Table should has 4 rows i.e 'B'         'x'          2   should be insert to table.

Comment: one problem: This answer By creating a loop to all users , Checked and All rows respectively, inserted into the table until to limited rows. In the event that maybe we want start with user 'B' or any thing. Suppose a different user is selected to start to see what I mean. In fact the user has selected to begin Consider a variable. for example : InitialNode='A' or InitialNode = 'B' or anything . so Consider the above scenario.

Comment: Did you understand what I commented?

Comment: Yes, but it was holyday here so I didn't have time to answer it :) I will answer it soon.

Comment: Ok.Thank You so much.I'm waiting.

Comment: @Eli, somthing is not clear to me. Let's say that I added user 'A', then it's related products brought users 'B' and 'C' to the list. Noe I move on to user 'B', and it's related products brought user 'D' to the list. How should I continue? with user 'C' from the previous set of related products, or with user 'D' from the last set of related products?

Comment: @Eli, have a look at my edit, and see if it fits your need.

Comment: yes. this is Ok. but for row_limit = 8 last row  for me is: 'C'         'z'          2 but for you is : 'A'         'z'          2 and  this answer (your answer) is true.  And it's true that there may not be a relationship between some  nodes

Comment: @Eli, you right, I updated the answer with a small correction.

Comment: hi. I have another question in this link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860990/how-to-set-a-name-for-the-cell?noredirect=1#comment68937770_40860990). can you view this link?

Comment: Hi. I solve problem in above link. can you view this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996390/create-a-xls-ro-csv-file-with-certain-header-of-rows-and-columns/41022533#41022533