# How to set a name for the cell

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array. when I want create a cell array that its name is : '0691008752' in this case an error :"Invalid field name"

```
cellUsers.('0691008752') = ....
```

I know the reason for this error is that a number is called. But I do not know how I can set this name for the cell.

Comment: I don't think you can... I believe it is.... well..... an "invalid field name"

Comment: It's simply not possible, but you can add a letter before your number in order to create a correct variable name. Ex `cellUsers.ID_0691008752`

Comment: You might want to look at what valid variable names can be in MATLAB: https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/variable-names.html

Comment: I can't any change in its name because this name used in many places in my program. and I must change all them. also there are many names etc

Comment: But... if your script contains errors... I mean,... you have to change it.

Comment: What MATLAB version do you have? You may want to look at [Map containers](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html?refresh=true), MATLAB's associative array. Or, have a look at `genvarname`.

Comment: May I ask where this problem comes from? Where does that number come from? Because indeed, prepending it with a string (`N = '0691008752';  cellUsers.(['ID_' N]) `) seems awfully simple to do...

Comment: My MATLAB version is R2014b.

Comment: I have a big list from product and users that reviews for those products. I want create a cell array for them that each user reviews for any product and overhand .  I use names of users and products in many places in my program. so I can't change this name

Comment: Create a struct array and include user ID as a field.

Comment: How can I create a structure while I keep for any user a list of products ?

Comment: Maybe have one field for the ID and one field for the list of products. It's really hard to say when you don't tell us what your data looks like. Also, if you want to respond to someone's message it's best to use `@beaker` for example, so they get notified that you responded. You get notified automatically since it's your question.

Comment: @beaker I have a data that it contains user ID and Product ID. any user comment for many product. one record in my file show userId and productId and rating of review and etc. I want create cell array for keep this list ( list of productId for any userId which that user comments for those product .). for example '0691008752' is one Id.since I work with this ID in maby places in program I can't change this ID.

Comment: @beaker I did not know for @ for notification. thank you

Comment: Please edit updates directly into your question rather than putting them in comments. The question itself should contain all of the information needed to answer. I still do not understand what your data looks like, though. What does the cell array look like that you were trying to build? Do you have one ID with multiple products? One record for each ID/product pair? All of the IDs that reviewed a particular product? We really need a sample of your data.

Answer (score 0):

**I agree with the comments above, prepending the field with a letter is the best solution for this problem..**

One way to make this consistent is to use:

```
fname = matlab.lang.makeValidName('0691008752')
```

---

Its not widely known but you **can** have fields which begin with number - its bad practice and will almost certainly leads to bugs....

So how to do it, 1st you need to use *mex*, if you see the mathworks [mex example](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97352-how-do-i-create-a-structure-array-from-a-c-mex-file-and-pass-it-to-matlab) and modify the appropriate line:

```
  memcpy(fieldnames[0],"Doublestuff",sizeof("Doublestuff"));
```

to:

```
  memcpy(fieldnames[0],"01234",sizeof("01234"));
```

After compiling and running you get:

[image]

Note: You can only access it through dynamic fields names.  To update the field you must use mex.

Comment: excuse me . Where file test.c was created and what is this file?

Comment: test.c is a modified version of the mex file in the link to the mathworks example.

Comment: sorry. I don't understand. I have not any file. can you more explain it for me?

Comment: The mex solution is not advisable and is added for completeness.  Its also complicated and requires a higher level of knowledge on Matlab coding etc... - **I advise you use the solution where you add a char in front of name.**