# Create a xls or csv file with certain header of rows and columns

Tags: c#, matlab

I have a list of ID in a matrix 'UserID'. I want create a xls or csv file that this UserID is its header lines. number of rows is:2200000 and number of columns is 11. Label of columns is years of 1996 - 2006 . I read this page :

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101309-how-do-i-use-xlswrite-to-add-row-and-column-labels-to-my-matlab-matrix-when-i-write-it-to-excel-in-m

but this code give me error. Although sometimes less is true for the number of rows and sometimes does not answer.Can anyone introduce a program that will do this? (with matlab or even c# code)

I write this code:

```
data=zeros(2200000,11);
data_cells=num2cell(data);
col_header={'1996','1997','1998','1999','2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2005','2006'};
row_header(1:2200000,1)=UserID;
output_matrix=[{' '} col_header; row_header data_cells];
xlswrite('My_file.xls',output_matrix);
```

and I get this error:

> The specified data range is invalid or too large to write to the specified file format. Try writing to an XLSX file and use Excel A1 notation for the range argument, for example, ‘A1:D4’.

Comment: We're not here to write code for you. Show us what you have tried and explain what is going wrong.

Comment: @Bas I updated this post.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `xlswrite` you are limited to the number of rows that your [Excel version permits](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html#inputarg_A):

> The maximum size of array A depends on the associated Excel version.

In Excel 2013 the maximum is 1048576, which is 1151424 fewer rows than your 2200000x11 matrix.

You better use [`csvwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html) to export your data, and refer also to the tip therein:

> csvwrite does not accept cell arrays for the input matrix M. To export a cell array that contains only numeric data, use [`cell2mat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) to convert the cell array to a numeric matrix before calling csvwrite. To export cell arrays with mixed alphabetic and numeric data... you must use [low-level export functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/write-to-delimited-data-files.html#br2ypq2-1) to write your data.

**EDIT:**

In your case, you should **at least** change this parts of the code:

```
col_header = 1996:2006;
output_matrix=[0, col_header; row_header data];
```

and you don't need to define `output_matrix` as a cell array (and don't need `data_dells`). However, you may also have to convert `UserID` to a numeric variable.

Comment: I wrote this code: `data=zeros(1000000,11);
    data_cells=num2cell(data);
    col_header={'1996','1997','1998','1999','2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2005','2006'};
    row_header(1:1000000,1)=userId(1:1000000);
    output_matrix=[{' '} col_header; row_header data_cells];
    csvwrite('My_file.csv',cell2mat(output_matrix));` but this give me error: `All contents of the input cell array must be of the same data type` I don't know reason of this error!! another question: can I save all 2200000 row in csv file?

Comment: As said in the documentation cited above you can only export a _"cell array that contains only numeric data"_. Your `col_header`, and maybe also the `row_header` are strings, and also, in your line `output_matrix=[{' '} col_header; row_header data_cells]` you add a char (`' '`) to the cell array, and make it a mixed one.