# Creating cells in Matlab

Tags: matlab, cell

I want to create  cells in matlab like the following:

```
 Q{1,1,1}=1;
 Q{1,1,2}=1;
 Q{2,2,1}=1;
 Q{2,1,2}=1;
```

However, I do not want to create this manually. In my application I have some vectors, one of which can be: `x=[1 2 3 4]`

And with this vector `x` I want to create

```
 P{1,2,3,4}=1
```

So the vector `x` kind of dictates the coordinates of the cell (sorry for bad english).

Since I dont know the length of the vector (it can change from case to case) I cannot do this:

```
       P{x(1,1),x(1,2),x(1,3),x(1,4)}=1;
```

What can I do here?

EDIT: I put the cells content with number "one" just for an example. The content of cell its gonna be linear matrix variable generated by the function `sdpvar` from the `yalmip toolbox`.

Comment: For starting you can look at the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792683/compact-matlab-matrix-indexing-notation), there they have explained nice indexing techniques.

Comment: A few questions to clarify yours : Will all your cells contain the same size of data? Do you absolutely need your result to be a cell array?

Comment: @BillBokeey please check the edit

Comment: Do you know the actual size of `P`or `Q`?

Answer (score 1):

First, if you only have numeric content perhaps a matrix is better then a cell.

---

To populate the spaces within a cell with a certain input you could do the following:

```
x = [1 2 3 4];
P(x) = {1}
P = 
    [1]    [1]    [1]    [1]
```

This also works when a index is skipped

```
x = [1 2 4 5]
P(x) = {1}
P = 
    [1]    [1]     []    [1]    [1]
```

To create your `Q` cell you should preallocate it to get the correct size, then you could use `sub2ind` to point out correct indexes

```
Q = cell(2,2,2)
% To populate all with 1
Q(:) = {1}
Q(:,:,1) = 
    [1]    [1]
    [1]    [1]
Q(:,:,2) = 
    [1]    [1]
    [1]    [1]
% To populate only a certain indexes
idx = sub2ind( size(Q), [1 1 2 2], [1 1 2 1], [1 2 1 2]);
Q(idx) = {1}
Q(:,:,1) = 
    [1]     []
     []    [1]
Q(:,:,2) = 
    [1]     []
    [1]     []
```

Comment: He wants to fill a particular index not all indexes @nilZ0r

Comment: @Optimus1072 Yes, and that is also what most of my code examples does. The `Q(:)` was merly done as an example to compare the `Q(idx)` with. I think the comments clarifies the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can do that without resorting to [eval](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html):

```
>>> x=[1,2,3,4];
>>> value=1 % or whatever you need here
>>> cmd=sprintf('%s%s%s','P{', strjoin(arrayfun(@(a) num2str(a),x,'UniformOutput',false),','), '}=value')
cmd = P{1,2,3,4}=1
>>> eval(cmd)
P = {1x2x3x4 Cell Array}
>>> P{1,2,3,4}
ans =  1
>>>
```

Comment: in your solution u are writing the number "1". This number is just an example and I dont want to write it manually, in fact I dont want to write a number to P. Mine 'P' should be an Linear Matrix Variable which I set using yalmip toolbox. I'm sorry for any trouble, but I wanted to simplify the question.